# Getting 400 Bad Request error Spring mvc + angular JS ajax request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring-mvc

This is my ajax request

```
$scope.check = function(ids) {


$http.post("logreport/move", {"ids":ids})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
};
```

& this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/move", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    GenericResponse move(@RequestParam(value = "ids") String ids
            ) {
        try {
            System.out.println(ids);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("INSIDE FAILED");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return new GenericResponse("Failed", ex.getMessage(), 500);
        }
        return new GenericResponse("Success", "", 200);
    }
```

Js logs

```
Remote Address:::1:8081

Request URL:http://localhost:8081/test/logreport/move
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

Request Headersview 
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8081
Origin:http://localhost:8081
Referer:http://localhost:8081/test/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payloadview 
{ids:[ 1]}
ids: [ 1]

Response Headersview 
Connection:close
Content-Length:971
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 12 May 2014 11:19:28 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: did u solve the issue ??

Comment: yes... I was passing requestParam as a parameter which is used for get request. Instead, I used '@RequestBody LogCommand jsonString' where Logcommand is commandObject which has field 'List<String> ids';